# Typo3 solr not showing search result

Tags: php, solr, typo3, extbase, typo3-6.1.x

I have successfully managed to install solr with typo3 6.2

`Solr version 4.2
Typo3 version 6.2
Typo3 solr extension 2.8`

Indexing processing is working fine as I am not getting anything in the devlog extension .But the problem is that when i try to search something in front end I am getting an error like this.

```
 Es tut uns leid. Ihre Suchanfrage konnte nicht verarbeitet werden.
```

And in Backend typo3 devlog am getting an error like this

`0: exception 'Apache_Solr_ParserException' with message 'Solr response does not appear to be valid JSON, please examine the raw response with getRawResponse() method' in /html/typo3/typo3conf/ext/solr/lib/SolrPhpClient/Apache/Solr/Response.php:206 Stack trace: #0 /html/typo3/typo3conf/ext/solr/lib/SolrPhpClient/Apache/Solr/Response.php(164): Apache_Solr_Response->_parseData() #1 /html/typo3/typo3conf/ext/solr/classes/class.tx_solr_search.php(365): Apache_Solr_Response->__get('response') #2 /html/typo3/typo3conf/ext/solr/pi_results/class.tx_solr_pi_results.php(167): tx_solr_Search->getNumberOfResults() #3 /html/typo3/typo3conf/ext/solr/classes/pluginbase/class.tx_solr_pluginbase_commandpluginbase.php(62): tx_solr_pi_results->getCommandList() #4 /html/typo3/typo3conf/ext/solr/classes/pluginbase/class.tx_solr_pluginbase_pluginbase.php(106): tx_solr_pluginbase_CommandPluginBase->render(NULL) #5 [internal function]: tx_solr_pluginbase_PluginBase->main('', Array) #6 /html/typo3/typo3_src-6.2.4/typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/ContentObject/ContentObjectRenderer.php(6579): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #7 /html/typo3/typo3_src-6.2.4/typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/ContentObject/UserContentObject.php(41): TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\ContentObjectRenderer->callUserFunction('tx_solr_pi_resu...', Array, '') #8 /html/typo3/typo3_src-6.2.4/typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/ContentObject/ContentObjectRenderer.php(863): TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\UserContentObject->render(Array) #9 /html/typo3/typo3_src-6.2.4/typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/Controller/TypoScriptFrontendController.php(3641): TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\ContentObjectRenderer->USER(Array) #10 /html/typo3/typo3_src-6.2.4/typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/Controller/TypoScriptFrontendController.php(3589): TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Controller\TypoScriptFrontendController->INTincScript_process(Array) #11 /html/typo3/typo3_src-6.2.4/typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/Controller/TypoScriptFrontendController.php(3557): TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Controller\TypoScriptFrontendController->recursivelyReplaceIntPlaceholdersInContent() #12 /html/typo3/typo3_src-6.2.4/typo3/sysext/cms/tslib/index_ts.php(231): TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Controller\TypoScriptFrontendController->INTincScript() #13 /html/typo3/typo3_src-6.2.4/index.php(28): require('/html/typo3/typ...') #14 {main}`

```
0: exception 'Apache_Solr_ParserException' with message 'Solr response does not appear to be valid JSON, please examine the raw response with getRawResponse() method' in /html/typo3/typo3conf/ext/solr/lib/SolrPhpClient/Apache/Solr/Response.php:206 Stack trace: #0 /html/typo3/typo3conf/ext/solr/lib/SolrPhpClient/Apache/Solr/Response.php(164): Apache_Solr_Response->_parseData() #1 /html/typo3/typo3conf/ext/solr/classes/class.tx_solr_search.php(365): Apache_Solr_Response->__get('response') #2 /html/typo3/typo3conf/ext/solr/pi_results/class.tx_solr_pi_results.php(167): tx_solr_Search->getNumberOfResults() #3 /html/typo3/typo3conf/ext/solr/classes/pluginbase/class.tx_solr_pluginbase_commandpluginbase.php(62): tx_solr_pi_results->getCommandList() #4 /html/typo3/typo3conf/ext/solr/classes/pluginbase/class.tx_solr_pluginbase_pluginbase.php(106): tx_solr_pluginbase_CommandPluginBase->render(NULL) #5 [internal function]: tx_solr_pluginbase_PluginBase->main('', Array) #6 /html/typo3/typo3_src-6.2.4/typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/ContentObject/ContentObjectRenderer.php(6579): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #7 /html/typo3/typo3_src-6.2.4/typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/ContentObject/UserContentObject.php(41): TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\ContentObjectRenderer->callUserFunction('tx_solr_pi_resu...', Array, '') #8 /html/typo3/typo3_src-6.2.4/typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/ContentObject/ContentObjectRenderer.php(863): TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\UserContentObject->render(Array) #9 /html/typo3/typo3_src-6.2.4/typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/Controller/TypoScriptFrontendController.php(3641): TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\ContentObjectRenderer->USER(Array) #10 /html/typo3/typo3_src-6.2.4/typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/Controller/TypoScriptFrontendController.php(3589): TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Controller\TypoScriptFrontendController->INTincScript_process(Array) #11 /html/typo3/typo3_src-6.2.4/typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/Controller/TypoScriptFrontendController.php(3557): TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Controller\TypoScriptFrontendController->recursivelyReplaceIntPlaceholdersInContent() #12 /html/typo3/typo3_src-6.2.4/typo3/sysext/cms/tslib/index_ts.php(231): TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Controller\TypoScriptFrontendController->INTincScript() #13 /html/typo3/typo3_src-6.2.4/index.php(28): require('/html/typo3/typ...') #14 {main}
```

Can someone help me with this ??

Any kind of help will appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does the server log say, and what does getRawResponse() return?

Comment: ~$this->_response->getStatusMessage()~ This function is returning an internal server error

Comment: Yes, but `getStatusMessage()` is not `getRawResponse()`. Anyway; the server log for your Solr server is what is interesting, as that's where the exception that triggers the error will be logged.

Comment: I have managed to find out the issue . /select was returning an internal server error. I have contacted the hosting guys and hope they can fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

as far as i know Typo3 solr extension 2.8 is not compatible with typo3 6.2. Use 3.0.0 instead